# Approval Process: 'e.parameter.approval' inside an "if" cycle

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to build an Approval flow with Google Apps Script. I would also like to add an "if" cycle that creates a Calendar event if `e.parameter.approval` is true.
So, everything works but the system doesn't recognize the "if" cycle. I've tried this:

```
function doGet(e){ 
var answer = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Approved!' : 'Not   this time';   
MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Request", 
            "The answer is: "+ answer);    

// here I tried both with (e.parameter.approval === 'true') and (check === answer) and also with "=" "==" and "==="...

var check = 'Approved!';
if(e.parameter.approval === 'true'){
    var calendar =     CalendarApp.getCalendarById('xxxxxxx')
    //create event 
    var newEventTitle = 'Event Test';
    var newEvent = calendar.createAllDayEventSeries(newEventTitle, 
                                                    Date, 
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(10),
    {description:'test'});       
    //get ID
    var newEventId = newEvent.getId();
     }
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
app.add(app.createHTML('<p><br><h2>An email was sent to '+  e.parameter.reply + ' saying: '+ answer + '</h2>'))
return app
}
```

Do you have any idea why the system skips the "if" cycle and goes directly to "var app"?

Comment: Did you check the type of "e.parameter.approval" by Logger.log() to see if it is a type of boolean?

Answer (score 0):

`e.parameter.approval` might not be returning anything.  I could be "undefined".  It could be "null".  You need to know for sure what `e.parameter.approval` is doing.  There is also the possibility that the `if` condition is actually working, but then there is an error that kills the code and stops it.  You'll need to debug every line.  Try using the "debug" tool.

[Apps Script Debugging Tool](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

You are using:

```
if(e.parameter.approval === 'true'){
```

The word 'true' is in quotes, which means it's a string value, not a true/false value.

Try:

```
if(e.parameter.approval === true){
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy, unfortunately it still doesn't work. The system sends the email and doesn't enter in the if cycle..

Comment: Try using the debugging tool:  [Google Documentation - Debugging Tool](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)  I updated my answer.